# Multiple readers / single writer lock using WinAPI

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, locking, readwritelock

Is there a commonly used, "best practice" read-write lock WinAPI implementation? I've only found [one implementation](http://www.glennslayden.com/code/win32/reader-writer-lock) and don't know if it's reliable.

Comment: As of Windows Vista/Server 2008, the WinAPI provides them natively: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937.aspx

Comment: @DarkFalcon: thank you, I've missed that. But I'm targeting Win XP as well.

Comment: Answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1008726/56778 provide links to several implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Win32 Critical Sections use some spins before wait. You have only 2 readers thread and rare writes. Just use a single Critical section for the whole thing, and I thing you willl get a very good performance/simplicity ratio. You may want to use RAII idiom to prevent exit path leaving the CS acquired.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such lock in WinXP API.
You can use shared_mutex from boost. [Example](http://pastebin.com/4ACktejA). Btw, such locks make sense when you have a lot of readers and a few of occasional writers. If it's not you case - just use mutex (critical section).

Comment: I know there's no such lock in the API, I can read MSDN. I'm not using Boost. I'm asking for _implementation_ using WinAPI.

Comment: I don't have many readers (let's say 2 threads total), but I have many reads and rare writes. Are you saying that regular critical section might be more effective than read-write lock?

Comment: Yeap, I meant a number of reads/writes. Read/write locks are quite expensive usually.